# Как правильно реагировать на недружелюбные комментарии?

Tags: обсуждение

К вопросу по реализации асинхронного ввода на `Python`
[Асинхронная работа с вебсокетами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1287107/%d0%90%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Пользователем @eri был оставлен комментарий:

> просто не блокируй инпут и будет тебе счастье

Я нахожу это сообщение несоответствующем политики сообщества, как минимум оно не отвечает на поставленный вопрос, а вообще оно разжигает негативное отношение между пользователями. Как правильно на них реагировать? Следует ли отправлять репорт по причине `Он недружелюбен или враждебен` или достаточно просто их игнорировать?

Comment: Возможно, комментарий немного глуповат (eri часто неаккуратен в формулировках...), но уж точно не недружелюбный

Comment: Не увидел ничего враждебного/недружелюбного, да согласен, комментарий глуповат, но не более того, поэтому я отклонил вашу тревогу.

Comment: Если вы так болезненно реагируете на подобные комментарии, то вы на пути к тому, что многие участники будут вас просто избегать

Comment: Почему нагло ставите на минусовке, чтобы заблокировать АККАУНТ!?

Comment: @Vladyslavя поставил минус, потому что читаю комментарий нормальным, вероятно, другие пользователи поставили минус потой же причине

Comment: я в так то тоже  иногда отвечаю в комментах в таком стиле, но ничего негативного не имею. иногда даже ставлю смайлик) чтобы не возникало подобных проблем)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Отправляйте репорт, он для этого и существует. Ну и игнорируйте одновременно с этим, нет смысла вступать в перепалку. Отправили репорт и забыли, всё.

Но конкретно о вашем случае - извините, а что вам тут не нравится? Что вас оскорбило?

> просто не блокируй инпут и будет тебе счастье

Вас оскорбило `просто`? Типа это намекает на то, что для @eri это просто, а вас он считает глупым? Или вас оскорбило `и будет тебе счастье`? Не очень понимаю, как пожелание счастья может разжигать негативное отношение.

Да, хочу обратить внимание, что я знаю про пассивную агрессию, троллинг, стёб и прочие феномены общения. Вот только ничего этого в сообщении @eri нет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В своем изначальном вопросе я спрашивал как реализовать асинхронный ввод. Человек же в комментарии пишет `не блокируй инпут`, учитывая специфику `python` это звучит как троллинг или стёб

Comment: @RoyalGoose , что ж я плохо знаю Пайтон, поэтому не вижу здесь троллинга. Однако, если он здесь и присутствует, то вряд ли вашу тревогу примут, потому что во-первых не все знают Пайтон, а во-вторых вряд ли кто-то будет вникать в ваш вопрос, чтобы понять адекватность комментария. Расцените это просто как плохой ответ. На Плохие ответы не надо ставить тревогу, можно поставить минус. Так как в данном случае это комментарий, и минус на него не поставить, просто игнорируйте.